# Using, .then but the code still runs out of sequence

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm running the below code on a schedule. It tests for every product status (using a for-next loop). I've chained the promises (.then) to cascade to the next execution block.
I've realised that Mongo methods run asynchronously and this is the probable reason why the for-next advances before the Mongo methods complete, and why execution starts to run in the wrong order.

I’ve tried adding await before updateOne & findOne, but this errors ‘await is only valid in async function’.

How is this situation resolved so it takes the async methods and moved to the next dbProduct when the inner loop is completed?

```
setInterval(function () {

    dbProduct.find({
       
        productStatus: 'Live' 
    }).then(dbProductRes => {


        for (var i = 0; i < dbProductRes.length; i++) {

            var product = dbProductRes[i].toObject();


            dbBuyer.findOne({
                buyerToken: winningBuyer

            }).then(res => {

                dbProduct.updateOne({
                    productId: product.productId
                }, {
                    $set: {
                       
                        productStatus: "Sold-PaymentSuccessful"
                    }
                }).exec();


            });


        }

    });

}, 15000);
```

**UPDATE:**

The above is a snippet of the original code. The final code needs a few additions. Between the .findOne and .updateOne two additonal methods are called; stripe.paymentMethods.list and stripe.paymentIntents.create. The latter requires a .catch but the updateOne should execute regardless.

Order of execution is:

```
 1   Get data in collection and loop (provide result into next method)
 2   findOne (provide result into next method)
 3   stripe.paymentMethods.list (provide result into next method)
 4   stripe.paymentIntents.create (provide result into next method)
 4.1   catch above method failure and updateOne then exit
 5   updateOne - Success of (2-4) then exit
```

If you could indicate in your answer how to implement 3-4, I should be able to put it all together. I think the stripe methods are thenable.
I can add full code if required.

Comment: All '.then' does is "at some time, when the promise is fulfilled, which might be in 1ns or it might be a literal week from now, execute a function". It does not make your code synchronous. It will not pause execution of your loop.

Comment: Thanks, How is it possible to pause the loop until async function has fulfilled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function () {

    dbProduct.find({
       
        productStatus: 'Live' 
    }).then(async function (dbProductRes) { // make function 'async' so we can use await


        for (var i = 0; i < dbProductRes.length; i++) {

            var product = dbProductRes[i].toObject();


            await dbBuyer.findOne({ // use await
                buyerToken: winningBuyer

            }).then(res => {
                // added return here too in case this is a promise as well:
                return dbProduct.updateOne({
                    productId: product.productId
                }, {
                    $set: {
                       
                        productStatus: "Sold-PaymentSuccessful"
                    }
                }).exec();


            });


        }

    });

}, 15000);
```

You can wait for promises with `await` as long as you are in an function marked `async`. (that function should also be awaited)

Also incase dbProduct.updateOne also returns a promise, I but a return in front of it.

Once you have async/await, you can pretty much rewrite the whole thing to use it:

something like:

```
setInterval(async function () {

    const dbProductRes = await bProduct.find({
       
        productStatus: 'Live' 
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < dbProductRes.length; i++) {
      var product = dbProductRes[i].toObject();
      const res = await dbBuyer.findOne({ // use await
           buyerToken: winningBuyer
      });
      await dbProduct.updateOne({
        productId: product.productId
      }, {
      $set: {
        productStatus: "Sold-PaymentSuccessful"
       }
       }).exec();
    });

}, 15000);
```

(assuming dbProduct.updateOne.exec() is also thenable)

Comment: The 1st block of code appears to work, but the 2nd doesn't enter the for-next loop. About the 1st block, I need to add another two methods between .findOne and updateOne, These being, stripe.paymentMethods.list and  stripe.paymentIntents.create. The latter requires a .catch but the updateOne should execute regardless. - Are you able to add pseudo code to your answer to help me understand how these additions would work pls?  I'll update answer to make question clearer.

Comment: Regarding 2nd block, after I console.log dbProductRes.length it reports 'undefined'. The 1st block works but I cannot add the additional methods without error (as mentioned in above comment)

Comment: This might be easier to figure out with a minimal example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
with promises from the standard library, and a program that anybody can run locally, like `require('fs/promises').readDir('.')` for example

Comment: I have added one more await in where it looks like it was missing in the second idea